# Could not find a part of the path ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, roslyn

I am trying to run an ASP.NET MVC (model-view-controller) project retrieved from TFS (Team Foundation Server) source control. I have added all assembly references and I am able to build and compile successfully without any error or warning.

But I get the following error in the browser:

> Could not find a part of the path
> 'C:\B8akWorkspace\B8akProject\B8akSolution\B8AK.Portal\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.

Here is a full screenshot of the error page.

[image]

After few days of research, I understood that [Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/) is a .NET compiler platform that offers advanced compiling features. However, I do not understand why my build is trying to find \bin\roslyn\csc.exe because I did not configure anything related to Roslyn. Nor did I intend to use Roslyn in my project.

Answer (score 594, accepted):

The problem with the default VS2015 templates is that the compiler isn't actually copied to the `tfr\bin\roslyn\` directory, but rather the `{outdir}\roslyn\` directory

Add this code in your .csproj file:

```xml
<Target Name="CopyRoslynFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="!$(Disable_CopyWebApplication) And '$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RoslynFiles Include="$(CscToolPath)\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslynFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)" RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This does not resolve my issue. Now I get **'Could not find file 'C:\B8akWorkspace\B8akProject\B8akSolution\B8AK.Portal\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'**. Please notice that when I create a new MVC project in VS2015 I don't see the mentioned configuration in .csproj and it runs perfectly fine in the browser

Comment: Thanks. I am now able to build and run the project in the browser after I downloaded the Roslyn directory and placing it in the /bin folder. I did not put the PstBuildEvent mentioned above and it still works. Maybe you want to edit your answer above and mention the need to manully placing the Roslyn files and to  better reflect the solution.

Comment: Well, in a normal situation; you should have the compiler inside your $(OutDir)roslyn\*.* folder, so this script will copy the compiler to the binfolder of your project. Apparently your installation of vs2015 did not include the compiler.

Comment: Hmm... Wouldn't the "start /min" mean that xcopy is running in a separate process while your build process continues merrily on its way creating a potential race condition?

Comment: Actually it is not a matter of VS. The compiler comes from a NuGet package - see my answer below. Adding the compiler binaries manually  to the project is not the right solution I think.

Comment: This should work without modifying the proj files. that's just fixing the symptom. doing a full rebuild should result in those files being there.

Comment: @Eyad Update MS dos.compiler in Nuget as well

Comment: I've used this to deploy in the AppHarbor also. Just make sure to include csc.exe and all *.dll in the packages folder of Microsoft.Net.Compilers package. I am using VS 2017 CE, ASP .NET MVC 5 targeting .NET 4.5.2 Framework just for reference.

Comment: I found updating Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform to 1.0.8 and Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.6.1 helped me a lot. I didnt need to add this extra target. Looks like something similar was added in a later version of the tooling: https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/commit/9408cd2aa2e394897564a0b8cd94b9350c0a3f89

Comment: I dont know but adding this target does not copy roslyn folder. I am using VS 2017.

Comment: I have updated the version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers to version 2.10.0 from the Nuget and it has been the solution for me. I'm using targetFramework="4.6.2"

Comment: suggest deleting obj and bin folder first before experimenting on newer the new ides.

Comment: Don't add code to your solution just because VisualStudio is not behaving! Look at the other answers below.

Comment: hmm.. similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54972645/1042705) -- Nugets fix it

Comment: Solved for me after removing `<system.codedom>` from `web.config`

Answer (score 1953):

**TL; DR**

run this in the Package Manager Console:

`Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r`

**More information**

This problem is not related to Visual Studio itself, so answers suggesting adding build steps to copy files over are rather a workaround. Same with adding compiler binaries manually to the project.

The Roslyn compiler comes from a NuGet package and there is/was a bug in some versions of that package (I don't know exactly which ones). The solution is to reinstall/upgrade that package to a bug-free version. Originally before I wrote the answer back in 2015 I fixed it by installing following packages at specific versions:

- Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.1.1
- Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.1

Then I looked into .csproj and made sure that the paths to packages are correct (in my case ..\..\packages\*.*) inside tags `<ImportProject>` on top and in `<Target>` with name "EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" on the bottom. This is on MVC 5 and .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: For some reason, I had to go into the Nuget Package Manager and manually select the latest version (3.6.0) for this to work, if anyone still faces the error after running the command above.

Answer (score 283):

A clean and rebuild worked for me!

Comment: I dont think the clean is required.  According to this discussion of the issue a **rebuild** not a regular build will always put the roslyn file back.  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15556

Comment: Rebuild resolved for me, I noticed this in the output `Copying file from "C:\Users\medmondson\Source\UK\Portal\Branches\v12\Source\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\csi.exe" to "bin\Debug\roslyn\csi.exe".`

Comment: DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.3, Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.3.2, VS Pro 2017 15.9.4 here. A clean/rebuild didn't work for me, even before and after restarting Visual Studio. Finally, a Build > Batch Build... > Rebuild All did the trick. It must have whispered just the right sweet-nothing to get VS to see it was missing the bin/roslyn directory in the output.

Comment: Clean and Rebuild did the trick for me. For those saying just doing rebuild will work...rebuild's behavior can be modified and does not always just do a clean and build. See #2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247480/4416750).

Comment: @pipedreambomb, you're correct but you won't want to clean/rebuild all the time.

Comment: I did a Rebuild at the solution level and fixed for me.  Over time I've found a few nuget packages where the default build doesn't trigger some of their setup properly, but a Solution Rebuild does.

Comment: Clean + Rebuild did the trick for me as well. The issue probably was that I've used another VS (2022 Preview) on the same project and probably it messed up with the compiler directory/version.

Comment: What is wrong with VS 2019? This simple method will kill the error.

Answer (score 210):

> **NOTE: If you are not interested in using Roslyn,**
> **follow this answer and remove it**

**The Roslyn:**

Your build is trying to find `\bin\roslyn\csc.exe` because the following packages have been added to your project. Just review your `packages.config` file, you can have both of them there

```
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

> **What is Roslyn and Who added them(packages) in the project :** If you’re using .net Framework 4.5.2 to create projects
> using VS2015, you might have noticed that the project templates use
> Roslyn by default. Actually, Roslyn is one of [open-source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview)
> compilers for .NET languages from Microsoft.
>
> **Why should we delete Roslyn:**
> If your project has Roslyn references and you are interested to deploy
> it on the server, you will get unwanted errors on the website as many
> hosting providers still have not upgraded their servers and hence do
> not support Roslyn. To resolve this issue, you will need to remove the
> Roslyn compiler from the project template.

**How to remove it:**

**1.**
Remove NuGet packages, use the following commands from Nuget Package Console

```
PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

**2.**
After you do this, your web.config file should be auto-updated. In case it is not, look for the below code in `web.config` file and if it is found, delete this piece of code.

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"></compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"></compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Comment: I have deleted all but still getting that error any idea?

Comment: This isn't really a solution if you actually *want* to use the new compiler and the new features.

Comment: You're advocating against the future.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I replaced all usages of "nameof" and some other C# 6 features. I agree with @cchamberlain that it would be best to keep up, but I don't have much sway on which versions of the .NET framework are available on our web server.

Comment: @cchamberlain why is it the future? I just think it should be straigthforward to use, but it looks many people are having troubles with it.

Comment: @Alisson - Roslyn is the direction things are going in. It contains newer language features, is more performant, cross-platform, and open source. It came out after the other tools - hence future. Nothing says you need to use it, most upgrades incur some cost. See the "Why Roslyn compilation in ASP.NET?" section: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications/

Comment: @cchamberlain I apologize if I expressed myself in a bad way, I just like to understand the benefits of things, rather than using just for the sake of it. If I understood correctly, if I used c# 7 features, I'd need Roslyn in order to build the project. Is that correct?

Comment: @Alisson no worries, didn't take anything in a bad way. Difficult to say the exact feature set since it varies across versions of each compiler over time, but yes you will get new language features sooner on Roslyn. I've personally used it to get the ability to write c# 7 syntax in razor views.

Comment: I only removed `<system.codedom>` block from production web.config & my application starts running like a charm.

Comment: if you want to publish MVC project to GoDaddy shared windows hosting, this is the answer. GoDaddy does not run executables like csc.exe

Answer (score 67):

Too late for an answer but still posting incase it helps anyone.

Following the below steps fixed the error for me:

1. delete packages folder
2. open VS
3. rebuild
4. observe that NuGet packages are restored, but bin\roslyn isnt created
5. unload project
6. reload project
7. rebuild
8. observe that the bin\roslyn has been created now.

Comment: Following these steps solved the problem for me.  Used Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: This is the only real solution, as it is a Visual Studio related problem, not a csc.exe one.

Answer (score 65):

#### 0. The quick fix

As already noted in [the currently highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391473),
the quick fix is to use the package manager, **Tools** > **Nuget Package
Manager** > **Package Manager Console**, to run

> ```
> Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r
> ```

[image: Packet Manager Console - how to open]

#### 1. Code to reproduce the error

Here is code that reproduces the error:
https://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/SrvrErr-reproduce.zip
(Originally from
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetDocs/tree/master/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client/sample/server/ProductsApp)

Consider trying the example code provided in the zip file above.
If no changes are made, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> will reproduce
the error.

[image: Server Error '/' in Application]

#### 2. A more robust solution

An alternative solution is to remove an attribute from the project's
`Web.config` file.
(`Web.config` is in the same directory as the `.csproj` file.)
This will automatically and silently recreate your packages if they
are missing.

Open the `Web.config` file in a text editor or in Visual Studio.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  ...
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

In the tag **configuration** > **system.codedom** > **compilers** >
**compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"**, completely remove
the `type` attribute.
– In short, remove the line that starts with
`type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider,` .
<sup>1</sup>

Visual Studio will take care of the rest.
– No more `Server Error in '/' Application`.

#### 3. HTTP Error 403

In the example provided above, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
will now result in an **HTTP Error 403**.

[image: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden]

Try replacing `http://localhost:64195` in your web browser with
`http://localhost:64195/api/products`.
The web API now displays correctly:

[image: A web API containing products]

---

As a provocation, I tried removing the whole `package` directory from
the Visual Studio project.
It was automatically and silently recreated as soon as the project was
rebuilt.

#### References

- [Project files that reproduce the error](https://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/SrvrErr-reproduce.zip)
- [The original project](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetDocs/tree/master/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client/sample/server/ProductsApp)

---

<sup>1</sup> Presumably, the same fix works for Visual Basic as well
as for C#, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Similar:
[Could not find file … bin\roslyn\csc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58154438).

Comment: This solved my problem, point number 2 fixed the issue! thank you.

Answer (score 64):

Here is a more MSBuild way of doing this.

```xml
<Target Name="CopyRoslynFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="!$(Disable_CopyWebApplication) And '$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RoslynFiles Include="$(CscToolPath)\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslynFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)" RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
</Target>
```

But I notice that the roslyn files are also in my bin directory (not in a folder).  The app seems to work, though.

Comment: You can put it anywhere in your .csproj file, at the same level as another <Target> tag.  I usually put it toward the bottom.

Answer (score 52):

As noted in [an issue in the Roslyn project on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15556#issuecomment-462519826), a solution (that worked for me) is to simply unload and reload the project in Visual Studio.

The "bin\roslyn" folder wasn't created on build or rebuild until I reloaded the project.

Answer (score 34):

I followed these steps and it worked perfectly

- Delete all the bin and obj folders
- Clean solution and rebuild
- Run this command in powershell

`Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r`

Answer (score 33):

I was also having same issue while running the project. Here are the steps that I followed.

1. Right click in solution
2. select Clean solution
3. After clean succeeded,Again build your project
4. Run the project again

This time I didn't see the same error. This works as expected.

Answer (score 26):

1. Clean Solution
2. Rebuild Solution 
   ,These two steps worked for me.

Comment: Works.  I accidentally pressed `Ctrl C` when I was in the middle of checking out a branch in `git` and it screwed my repo up.  `git reset --hard` didn't work, so I `git clean -xdf` and had to rebuild the project.  However I ran into this error so I simply cleaned and rebuilt the project again and it worked for me.

Comment: This answer already existed for years before you posted it.

Answer (score 24):

After trying all of the fixes with no cigar I fixed it by updating this Nuget Package in Visual Studios:

**Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform**

*Mine was from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 for reference (The error no longer shows)*

Comment: I did this too. Now the `roslyn` folder is created in my output path. I also see no "roslyn" reference in my csproj. It *could be* that `Target Name="CopyRoslyn...` is a VS2015 thing and not necessary in (the version of) 2017 I have. Worth to note: Since I updated DotnetCompilerPlatform *before* I played around with adding a copying target (the one I mentioned) I have a cleaner csproj.

Answer (score 19):

[image: NuGet Package Manager]

You need to install Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix,
was especially created for that error

Comment: This didn't work - I suspect that package is not actually for this exact purpose.

Comment: I tested with VS 2017 and it works fine, it could be an issue with other versions.

Comment: I am not installing random packages from random person with 'dsx' as nickname. That is big security no...

Comment: @Mateusz or one that would fix my non-APS.NET [sic] folder structure

Answer (score 19):

- Right click on your project and select Manage Nuget Packages
- Find "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform"
- Simply Update to an older or newer version (doesn't matter which), and then update again back to your original version.

This re-installs all the dependencies and files of the package (like csc.exe)

[image: Nuget - DotNetCompilerPlatform]

Comment: thanks, downgrading to 3.11.0.0 worked for me. I think there is something wrong with the latest new version, 4.1.0

Answer (score 19):

For VS 2019 remove the following node completely:

```
<system.codedom>
</system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 17):

In my case, before trying any of the other solutions, I switched to a "Release" configuration, rebuilt (the folder got created) and then switched back to "Debug", while the folder remained intact.

This was a checkout from source control of an older solution and apparently the original (automatic) package restore and building the project didn't create that folder in the bin directory.

Note that at time of writing this, the blamed component has reached v.2.

Answer (score 14):

Updating nuget packages worked for me 
Right click on the solution > Manage NuGet packages for solution 
and update all the packages and specially:
**Microsoft.Net.Compilers** 
and **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform**

Answer (score 12):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/13) with [Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform) 1.0.6. Downgrading to 1.0.5 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 11):

So, [Rob Cannon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33004292/1524502) essentially worked for me, but I had to tweak a handful of the options. Specifically, I had to remove the condition on the target, as well as change the Include attribute, as $CscToolPath was empty when the project was being built on our build server. Curiously, $CscToolPath was NOT empty when running locally.

```
<Target Name="CopyRoslynFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" >
  <ItemGroup>
    <RoslynFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.1.1\tools\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <MakeDir Directories="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslynFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)" RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: The behavior is even worse. Locally, if you go to your _package_ folder and delete the two folders *Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.n.n* and build you code, then the $CscToolPath will be empty. If you build a second time, then it'll not be empty. The problem happens all the time on your build server, because it is always considered as a "first build". Your code works perfectly, but if you update the _Microsoft.Net.Compilers_ package, then you'll have to update the _.csproj_. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this solution will fail (or has to be adjusted) if the Microsoft.Net.Compilers's version changes.

Comment: I upgraded the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform and then was able to proceed.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I have had issue in Jenkins when it tried to deploying it in Octopus with following error:

```
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969: Failed to build the path for '\bin\roslyn\csc.exe' relative to 'T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test': Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.. See the inner exception for more details. [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969: System.Exception: Failed to build the path for '\bin\roslyn\csc.exe' relative to 'T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test': Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.. See the inner exception for more details. ---> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969:    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969:    at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969:    at OctoPack.Tasks.Util.OctopusPhysicalFileSystem.GetPathRelativeTo(String fullPath, String relativeTo) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\20ba9f2e0d5e4022\source\OctoPack.Tasks\Util\OctopusPhysicalFileSystem.cs:line 211 [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969:    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969:    at OctoPack.Tasks.Util.OctopusPhysicalFileSystem.GetPathRelativeTo(String fullPath, String relativeTo) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\20ba9f2e0d5e4022\source\OctoPack.Tasks\Util\OctopusPhysicalFileSystem.cs:line 224 [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969:    at OctoPack.Tasks.CreateOctoPackPackage.AddFiles(XContainer nuSpec, IEnumerable`1 sourceFiles, String sourceBaseDirectory, String targetDirectory, String relativeTo) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\20ba9f2e0d5e4022\source\OctoPack.Tasks\CreateOctoPackPackage.cs:line 443 [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCT-1676060969:    at OctoPack.Tasks.CreateOctoPackPackage.Execute() in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\20ba9f2e0d5e4022\source\OctoPack.Tasks\CreateOctoPackPackage.cs:line 190 [T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj]
Done Building Project "T:\workspace\machine.engine\Machine.engine.Test\Machine.engine.Test.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED
```

**Cause**

After spending some time, I was using an internal developed component that was using `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`. The reason the internal component was using `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` was to overcome this issue ([C#: throw invalid expression compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156277/c-throw-invalid-expression-compilation)) and was solved this way ([How to use C# 7 with Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015)). This result in, when I installed the component on the main program, the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` get added it selves automatically.

**Solution**

My work around was, uninstall following from our internal component by (following @malikKhalil answer)

```
PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

And chose C# 7 compiler in Jenkins instead of C# 6 and rebuild, this is to ensure everything is working and building correctly.

Than finally in my main program I tried to update my internal component. And everything than build again. It has built without any problems or issues.

Answer (score 10):

Per a comment by Daniel Neel above :

version 1.0.3 of the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform Nuget package works for me, but version 1.0.6 causes the error in this question

Downgrading to 1.0.3 resolved this issue for me.

Comment: 1.0.6 has a bug: https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/13

Comment: 1.0.7 is still affected in certain scenarios https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/17

Answer (score 9):

In my case I just needed to go to the bin directory in Visual Studio Solution Explorer (web application project) and include the roslyn project directly. By right clicking the folder and selecting Include In Project.  And check in the solution again to trigger the build process.

The roslyn folder was not included by default.

Answer (score 9):

Upgrading `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you were adding ASPNETCOMPILER to compile your Razor views in MVC, like in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc), then change PhysicalPath to place where Roslyn nuget package is located (usually pointed via **$CscToolPath** variable):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(CscToolPath)" />
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case by just Deleting everything inside the bin folder and recompiling did all the work for me.

Comment: I think this is more simple and effective. Usually I get this error after cloning a project  from a repository into a new computir.

Comment: After trying this, I got 403 Forbidden from IIS Express when running in the debugger. Restarting Visual Studio did not help, either, but rebooting Windows did.

Comment: This repeats the [answer from user1903050](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187980/2756409) from a few years prior. And the [answer from Masoud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341249/2756409)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, similar to Basim, there was a NuGet package that was telling the compiler we needed C# 6, which we didn't.

We had to remove the NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` which then removed:

1. `<package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform"
   version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />` from the
   packages.config file
2. `<system.codedom>
     <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
   </system.codedom>`

In the `system.codedom` node, you can see why it was bringing in roslyn: `compilerOptions="/langversion:6`

Comment: All I had to do was uninstall the NuGet package "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" and that solved it for me (my project targets .NET 4.5.2).

Comment: This worked for me. You'll also want to remove Microsoft.Net.Compilers as there is no reason to keep this additional dependency around either.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with the default VS2015 templates is that the compiler isn't actually copied to the `{outdir}_PublishedWebsites\tfr\bin\roslyn\` directory, but rather the `{outdir}\roslyn\` directory. This is likely different from your local environment since `AppHarbor` builds apps using an output directory instead of building the solution "in-place".

To fix it, add the following towards end of `.csproj` file right after xml block `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">...</Target>`

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    if not exist "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn" md "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"
    start /MIN xcopy /s /y /R "$(OutDir)roslyn\*.*" "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Reference: https://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/78633-cant-build-aspnet-mvc-project-generated-from-vstudio-2015-enterprise

Comment: The /d option copies only newer files (stands for "date"). Keep in mind deploying into cloud/azure where the time could be behind/in front of the local time.

Answer (score 7):

Open the project file and **remove** all references with Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0....

Open web.config and **remove** all system.codedom compilers attributes

Answer (score 7):

Delete the Bin folder in your solution explorer and Build the solution again. That would solve the problem

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when installing my application on the server when everything worked perfectly on localhost.

None of these solutions woorked, I always had the same error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myApp\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'
```

I ended up doing this:

- on my setup project, right clic, view > file system
- create a `bin/roslyn` folder
- select add > files and add all files from `packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools`

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I have webproject without csproj file and solutions mentiond here did not work for me.

Changing target .NET framework, reinstalling packages (`Update-Package -reinstall`) and then building the project worked for me. You can even change target framework back after this operation(make suere you reinstall nuget packages again after).

Comment: This is a "website project". I used this command to just reinstall the one package: `update-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -reinstall`

Answer (score 4):

Other than deleting the Bin diretory from all projects inside the solution, delete the obj folders too.

In the main solution diretory remove the folder .vs

Worked for me when trying to bring an already done project into a blank solution created on git.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had this issue when i was running two visual studio IDE simultaneously. So the solution was to clean the project and close the other instance.

Answer (score 4):

Reboot Windows.

This is the only solution that worked for me after trying rebuild, delete contents of `bin` and rebuild, restart Visual Studio.

It's yet another example of how terrible C#/.NET build tools are.

**I think (after reading many of the answers), the overall conclusion is that the cause and solution of this problem heavily depends on the setup and project, so if one answer does not work, just try another. Try non-intrusive/destructive solutions, such as restarting Visual Studio, rebooting, rebuilding, etc., FIRST, before messing with NuGet packages or reinstalling development tools. Good luck!**

(NOTE: Using Visual Studio 2019, and project file was originally created in Visual Studio 2015. Maybe this helps someone investigate the issue)

(EDIT: Could this be caused by not rebooting after installing/modifying the Visual Studio installation or updating Visual Studio when the installer prompts to reboot?)

Comment: closing visual studio and deleting the contents from the bin folder and rebuild/clean solution or project fixed this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I tried multiple top answers until the below steps worked (ASP.NET project targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2, Visual Studio 2019 on a system with crazy restrictive group policies, March 2021).

I needed to:

- run VS as **Admin**
- in package manager console run

  ```
  Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -v 2.0.1
  ```
- Clean & Rebuild Solution

Without running VS as Admin, group policies blocked ps1 scripts that Update-Package needed to run.

PS. Before this worked, I tried numerous other answers (and ran git reset --hard after they failed). I do not know if any of them contributed to this eventually working. I tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780433/4658148
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391473/4658148
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484473/4658148
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62136000/4658148
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341249/4658148
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308385/4658148

Answer (score 4):

For those struggling through this when compiling on the build server (TFS or Bamboo), I was able to solve this by removing the "clean" option from the "/t:" msbuild options.

Answer (score 3):

my solution is using Nuget to update below items to latest version:
 - Microsoft.Net.Compilers
 - Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
Then rebuilt the project. Since my project is a website so no *.csproj file.
The error above appears when I tried to view a cshtml in browser.

The error fixed after the two items above updated to latest version.
I am in VS2015 and windows7 SP1

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on the server I was deploying to, and determined that I did not need

> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

So, I uninstalled it via nuget, and removed the reference in the web config. No more issues.

I originally tried to added target node to the .proj file as mentioned in some of the other answers, but that just lead to another error where the `msbuild` could not copy the `pagefile.sys` which seemed from what I read to be a bug in the nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for this. That worked for me. Just wondering if you know why DotNetCompilerPlatform was added in the first palce, what package usually adds this?

Comment: @russelrillema it is a default for MVC/WebAPI projects and I believe it is used for dynamic compilation. [Replacement CodeDOM providers that use the new .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") compiler as a service APIs. This provides support for new language features in systems using CodeDOM (e.g. ASP.NET runtime compilation) as well as improving the compilation performance of these systems.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform)

Answer (score 3):

The following solved this issue for me:

- Updating to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (using the installer app)
- Clean and rebuild the solution

Comment: Clean & rebuild was enough for me since I already have VS2017

Answer (score 2):

Add PropertyGroup to your .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>
    if not exist "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn" md "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"      
    start /MIN xcopy /s /y /R "$(OutDir)roslyn\*.*" "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"
  </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, all variables are undefined (empty)

Answer (score 2):

I had this error for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` `1.06` but also with `1.0.7` that worked for @PrisonerZERO. However when Microsoft released `1.0.8` 2017-10-18 it finally started working for me again and I did not have to downgrade.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/

Answer (score 2):

On my case, i Noticed that the "build" folder was not present in "packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0" path. And that was the reason why the roslyn folder was not beeing created.

So the solution for me was:

1. Clean solution
2. Go to Nuget Package Manager
3. Uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
4. Clean solution
5. Install Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform again from Nuget package manager.
6. Clean/Rebuild

And there you go. None of the solution above worked for me . Hope this helps anyone

Comment: This seems to repeat many answers already present.

Answer (score 2):

I had a project running in VS2019 and then i open(in VS2019) another project for the first time and i got the above issue. what I did as follow:

1. I close the running project,
2. Clean and rebuild the new project

Only point no. 2 was not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Change Target Framework in properties and then rebuild project Or build project then Unload and Reload project and then rebuild again.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the build from also copying the Roslyn files to the bin directory, you have to also comment out this line that gets placed at the top of your Web application project:

```
<!--  <Import Project="..\..\..\DAS\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.1\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\DAS\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.1\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" /> -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after updating some packages through NuGet. A rebuild (instead of a normal build) has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating DotNetCompilerPlatform.
Solved by Restarting Visual Studio > Clean Project > Build Project.

Answer (score 1):

FYI...

As of 8/31/2017 upgrading to Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.7 is works.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the following easy way-:

- Create a new project of similar type anywhere in your system. Build it and copy over the roslyn folder to your bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these answers are referring to the Nuget packages and/or cleaning and reloading your project.

If you have WCF service references and invalid endpoints, you can also get this error message. Make sure your endpoints are correct and update the service configuration with the correct endpoint in the .config and when you configure the service reference from the GUI.

[image: Image of Service Reference Configuration GUI]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the WebAPI and MVC project files to not build views:

```
<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
```

This resolved my TFS 2015 Build server error with roslyn. Still not sure why csc.exe was copied to \bin\csc.exe, yet the publish process was looking for \bin\Roslyn\csc.exe...couldn't find the transformation causing that discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error on a Jenkins build server running MSBuild, which outputs the build files to a separate folder location (_PublishedWebsites). Exactly the same - the roslyn folder was not in the bin directory, and all the roslyn files were lumped in with the bin files.

[@igor-semin 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37205809/1310014) was the only thing that worked for me (as I am using the C# 6 language features, I cannot simply uninstall the nuget packages as per other answers), but as I am also running CodeAnalysis, I was getting another error on my deployment target server:

*An attempt to override an existing mapping was detected for type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ICompilationUnitSyntax with name "", currently mapped to type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax, to type Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax.*

The reason for this is that as the roslyn files are getting dumped into the main bin directory, when you run the xcopy to recreate them in the nested roslyn folder, you now have 2 copies of these files being compiled and there is a clash between them. After much frustration I decided on a 'hack' fix - an additional post-build task to delete these files from the bin directory, removing the conflict.

The .csproj of my offending projects now looks like:

................... more here ......................

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEvent>
   if not exist "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn" md "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"
   start /MIN xcopy /s /y /R "$(OutDir)roslyn\*.*" "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Roslyn"
 </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="DeleteDuplicateAnalysisFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
   <!-- Jenkins now has copies of the following files in both the bin directory and the 'bin\rosyln' directory. Delete from bin. -->
   <ItemGroup>
     <FilesToDelete Include="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis*.dll" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" />
</Target>
```

................... more here ......................

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with the publishing pipeline (which produces a _PublishedWebsites directory), and used this as a Target in the project:

```
<Target Name="CopyRoslynCompilerFilesToPublishedWebsitesDirectory" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="Exists('$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(TargetName)')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslyCompilerFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(TargetName)\bin\roslyn" ContinueOnError="true" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

The downside is that there will be two copies of the Roslyn files in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after renaming a solution and some included projects, and playing around with removing nuget packages. I compared the new project with the last working project, and found the following lines were missing and needed to be added back in:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Doing so resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, our team don't want to keep 'packages' folder, so we put all dlls in other directory like 'sharedlib'.

I used build event to solve this problem.

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" (
goto :release
) else (
goto:exit
)

:release
if not exist $(TargetDir)\roslyn mkdir $(TargetDir)\roslyn

copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)..\..\Shared Lib\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\tools\Roslyn45\*" "$(TargetDir)\roslyn"
goto :exit

:exit
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me.  After doing a folder compare before/after vs my expected committed files, i discovered that GIT was ignoring a required folder.  If you are tracking the compiler in a repository, make sure the BUILD folder is tracked.  If it's not, the compiler won't ever be built and will throw this exact error after publish.  I added this line to my **.gitignore** file:

```
!**/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1/build/
```

and now it's deploying to other computers properly.

Answer (score -1):

### Issue

Be aware that the NuGet PM breaks the Rosalyn behavior.  Click `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`  If an update Exists for `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`, `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`, or `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.netcore`, update them and the Solution will break!  This occurs because the ASP Sites templates are set to use specific versions at project creation.  To See the problem, click Show All Files in the Solution Explorer.

### Fix

At project creation the `$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin` doesn't exist, therefore when Rosalyn is added as a dependency by NuGet it installs it properly. After Updating the Solution Packages, the `$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin` directory looks like so:

`$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\bin\rosalyn`

The easiest fix is to Cut & Paste rosalyn to the proper location, and then delete the extra `bin` folder.  You can now Refresh the page and the site will load.

Answer (score -1):

The answer for this is different for Website project and Web application Project.
The underlying issue is same that 
NuGet package is behaving differently on different machine. It may be rights issue or some execution policy which stops it from copying to Bin folder
As you know Roslyn is new compiler. 
you should have it in Bin folder for these Projects
Go to your website NuGet Packages  check this Folder 
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0
\code\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0
Do you see it ? 
Can you see code\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\tools\RoslynLatest in it 
Now as part of compiling this Folder should get copied to your website under bin like this.
\code\WebSite1\Bin\Roslyn  some how that is not happening for you .
Try running Visual studio as Admin .
Copy Roslyn folder manually.
Try uninstall and install of NuGet Package.
Remember this package compile your folder and if its not there you cannot compile anything and so you cannot add anything too.
Try copying this package to offline version
tools -> options-> nuget package Manager->Package source-> Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages

Answer (score -1):

Install nudget package: Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.BinFix/1.0.0

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same issue got resolve by running the below command in nuget console

Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 3.3.1