# Compiler error Visual studio mac

Tags: c#, git, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on Visual Studio for Mac preview. My project comes from a git repository and when i try to compile it, the compiler gives me this error:

*Error: Error building target IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Link'  Key being added: 'Link' (NameOfTheProject)*

I can't understand this error and i didn't find any resource about it on the web. Can you please help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: First thing I would try to do is to Clean/Rebuild the project.

Comment: Unfortunately i tried it, same result :(

Comment: What kind of project? .NET Core and mobile projects?

Comment: It's a ASP.NET MVC web application with framework 4.5.2 @LexLi

Comment: @EmanueleClemente then it won't work. Currently I think Microsoft has no plan to support .NET Framework stuffs on Mac.

Comment: @EmanueleClemente I have the exact same issue that you are having.  If you figure out a solution, could you let me know what you come up with? Thanks!

Comment: @LexLi But if i create a new MVC project it works. The error appears only on a project from a git repository.

Comment: @EmanueleClemente because the VS 2015 template uses things that Mono does not fully support. VS for Mac does ship a suitable template, but I wonder if that's what you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and the solution is just remove two references. like this

Microsoft.Net.Compilers

Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompierPlataform

I found this solution at [roslyn compiler not copied to AspnetCompileMerge folder using msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777162/roslyn-compiler-not-copied-to-aspnetcompilemerge-folder-using-msbuild)