# Error at building project in MonoDevelop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, monodevelop

I tried to build my existing MVC application with MonoDevelop. The error I get is this:
`Error: Error building target IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Link'  Key being added: 'Link'`

The project has been developed on another machine running Windows and using VS2017 and the error I get when running the project on my machine running Linux.

The command `grep IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup * -R` in my terminal returns `packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.5/build/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props:  <Target Name="IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences" >`

But I'm stuck at this point. Do you have any recommendations about what should I do next to solve this error?

Comment: Please share with us the content of .csproj especially the tag (or tags if there are more then one) `IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup`

Comment: Here it is: https://coltaemanuela.github.io/FireEdit/?id=csproj

Comment: I opened the documents where "IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup" was found and I commented the sections which contained it and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40819159/1537726) one possible solution is to remove these references from your project:

- Microsoft.Net.Compilers
- Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompierPlatform