# Publish: Could not find a part of the path … \obj\DEV\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, nuget, roslyn

I recently added the new .NET compiler NuGet packages (Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatfor) to an existing older MVC.NET website. Now when trying to publish the website I get the following exception:

> Could not find a part of the path …
>   \obj\DEV\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'

I have tried everything mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe), but nothing worked. It is, after all, a slightly different problem. The problem mentioned in that post is build exceptions, my solution builds fine locally. Uninstalling the NuGet packages works, but that's not really a solution.

The issue is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777162/roslyn-compiler-not-copied-to-aspnetcompilemerge-folder-using-msbuild) one, but that also has no solution.

Publish output:

```
4>------ Publish started: Project: Jdn.ArticleCatalogue.Web, Configuration: DEV Any CPU ------
4>Connecting to \\vm-arcawebdev01\WEBSITES\ArticleCatalogue...
4>Transformed Web.config using D:\DOTNET\Local\Logistics.Web\Portal\DEV\Application Projects\Article Catalogue\Jdn.ArticleCatalogue.Web\Web.DEV.config into obj\DEV\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
4>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
4>obj\DEV\AspnetCompileMerge\Source.
4>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "D:\DOTNET\Local\Logistics.Web\Portal\DEV\Application Projects\Article Catalogue\Jdn.ArticleCatalogue.Web\obj\DEV\AspnetCompileMerge\Source" "D:\DOTNET\Local\Logistics.Web\Portal\DEV\Application Projects\Article Catalogue\Jdn.ArticleCatalogue.Web\obj\DEV\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir" -keyfile "..\..\..\Solution Items\Jdn.LogisticsPortal.snk" 
4>ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPRUNTIME: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\DOTNET\Local\Logistics.Web\Portal\DEV\Application Projects\Article Catalogue\Jdn.ArticleCatalogue.Web\obj\DEV\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Comment: Are you publishing the `roslyn` folder inside the `bin` folder?

Comment: I'm using the build in 'Publish Website' functionality of Visual Studio Web Projects.

Comment: Which build are you using  in TFS,the old XAML build or the new vNext build? And could you share the detailed MSBuild Arguments and more related log?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT: I'm not entirely sure. I use the 'Publish' option of the right click menu of a Visual Studio Web Project (see: http://i.imgur.com/ThZLFtB.png). Which logs are you looking for and where could I find those? I have included the generated Build Output from Visual Studio in my initial question.

Comment: @Schoof If so, looks like you are encountering issue locally. It's not related to TFS  build. Suggest you remove `tfsbuild` tag and add some tag such as `msbuild`, `Nuget`. Since without the newly Nuget package installed, everything works well.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT We also have a TFS build running that gets the same exception. MSBuild Arguments: `/p:OutputPath=bin/$(BuildConfiguration) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="DEV"`. But you are correct, I changed the tags. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find a part of the path ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe)

Comment: @jrummell: I linked to that in my question and stated that none of the answers work and it's a slightly different issue.

Comment: @Schoof have you tried downgrading the package to 1.0.5 or 1.0.3 as suggested in that question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/13) whereby the Roslyn binary wasn't being copied correctly to the publish directory. It should be fixed if you install `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.7`.

There seem to be some residual issues which are being [tracked here](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/17).

Comment: This indeed has fixed the issue! Thank you :)

Comment: Upgraded to `1.0.7`, still not working. I believe I just dislike Roslyn, it's been 2 hours trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem accourred to me while publish MVC .NET application to my local path. I solved the problem delete **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** by nuget package.