# csc.exe has stopped working causes Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I run my application on `VS2015` I get a window saying that `csc.exe has stopped working` like below:
[image]

After I click to close the program I get another error in the browser saying:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

[image]

Detailed Compiler output looks like below:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>D:_myURL\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
> /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+
> /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
> /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll"

What could be the issue?

Comment: The compiler's crashing. -532462766 or `0xe0434352` is just the generic code for any .NET exception. Check the event log for more details, or hook up a debugger.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I faced the same issue and I would suggest to follow the steps described [here](http://celticcodingsolutions.com/Blog/post/2015/09/18/csc-exe-crash-in-visual-studio-2015-when-running-asp-net-project):

- Close all instances of Visual Studio 2015 and if they don't do it automatically disappear, end tasks for all the VBCSCompiler processes.
- In your Visual Studio project under Bin folder you will see a roslyn folder (new for VS 2015)
- Delete the roslyn folder and all contents within.
- Restart Visual Studio 2015
- Re Build your project and all should be well again.

Comment: I take it back. deleting the roslyn folder leads to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe

Comment: I just found out that you don't have to close all your Visual Studio instances.  
1. Just stop all debug sessions
2. Clean Solution
3. Navigate to you ~/bin folder.
4. Shift+Delete you roslyn folder.
5. Rebuild Solution (and the Roslyn folder should appear)  
6. Run

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue.After I delete files in the bin folder and run the application.The issue is fixed.

Comment: one of the easiest step, that worked for me. highfive

Answer (score 0):

-532462766 according to my efforts to help you, is an error that occurs when an unhandled exception is thrown.

I am sorry, i cannot help you much. My suggestion is to start debugging your program, by either using a debugger, or by wrapping some bits of your code in try-catch blocks, like in the example below:

```
try {
    // Your code here
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Error caught"); 
}
```

And your details are very vague. I can only help If you show the line/group of code causing the error.

**However**, the fact that csc.exe stops responding is intriguing, You can try to uninstall .NET Framework and reinstall it, you can find the downloads here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download And if reinstalling it doesn't help, I am  terribly sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of errors, I always go to Event Viewer `eventvwr`. Please expand Windows Logs and click Application.

[image]

If you cannot see your entry, you can easily filter it out - right click on
Application and choose Filter Current Log. Check Critical, Warning and error and push OK. After that, you'll see detailed information in main view.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps are what i did and worked for me.

## 1. Remove virtual directory from the IIS.

- Open IIS (Start -> Run -> inetmgr -> enter)
- Find your project virtual directory (expand hostname -> Sites -> Default Web Site -> MyProjectName)
- Delete the virtual directory (Right click -> Remove)

## 2. Create virtual directory again via the VS 2015

- Switch to Visual Studio
- Open project properties ( Right click to MyProjectName on the Solution Explorer -> Properties)
- Open the Web tab from the left menu
- Click Create Virtual Directory button Under the Servers section.

Run the project again and It's done.

Hopefully it helps to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

]I found I had to end task "VBCSCompiler.exe" in TaskManager. There after I could successfully clean the solution /bin directory and the error disappeared.

[image]