# switch case syntax specifies a data type

Tags: c#, syntax, c#-7.0

Today at work I we did a code review as we do now and again, but today I saw a syntax I haven't seen before. I have searched the web for it to no avail, and what is even more interesting is that, despite using the same version of Visual Studio, that is, 2017 Enterprise, I get a syntax error at home when I try to recreate what I saw at work today. It looked something like this:

```
switch (someObject) {
    case TypeOne valueOne: action1(); break;
    case TypeTwo valueTwo: action2(); break;
    // ... and so on
}
```

In other words, it looked like they checked both type and value in one go. But like I said, I can't find it on the internet and I get a syntax error at home. I know there's a lot of new stuff in C# 7, especially in terms of syntactic sugar. Can you explain this?

Comment: Check "Switch statements with patterns" in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/

Comment: It is a new feature of C# 7 called pattern matching [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) search for `Pattern Matching`

Comment: Make sure you set your compiler to use C# 7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681882/expression-bodied-get-set-accessors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [new C# 7 feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/): pattern matching switch statement which matches on types.

What this code does, giving the first branch:

- It checks if `someObject` is, derives from or implements type `TypeOne`.
- If so, it casts `someObject` to type `TypeOne` which is assigned to `valueOne`.
- Then it enters the case block where you can directly use `valueOne`.