# Getter and Setter Aliasing in C#

Tags: c#, variables, instantiation, getter-setter

How would I go about aliasing a variable from it's plural form so that referencing the plural form changes or returns the single form?

I have a global variable as such with a Getter and Setter:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

And would like to set up an aliased variable `UserNames` that would return `UserName` and when set would modify `UserName`?

I've tried `public string UserNames { get => UserName; set => UserName = UserNames }` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Your setter would need to be `UserName = value`

Comment: This isn't "aliasing"; there's a [C# feature called aliasing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765(v=vs.71).aspx) already. This is just forwarding. `a.get` returns `b`.

Comment: No array involved here, just trying to get the variable name UserName(s) to reflect the variable with name UserName.

Comment: You are converting an array to a single string.  So you would need to use something like CSV (seperated by commas).  So try this :  public string[] UserNames { get { return UserName.Split(new char[] {','});} set { UserName = string.Join(",",value);}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# <7.0

```
public string UserNames { get { return UserName; } set { UserName = value; }}
```

C# 7.0

```
public string UserNames { get => UserName; set => UserName = value; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Almost, you have to use `value` in your setter.

```
public string UserNames { get => UserName; set => UserName = value; }
```

Comment: Note that this syntax requires C# 7 to be available

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - true; the attempt in the OP is posted using c# 7 syntax so I figured an answer in c# 7 syntax was warranted.

Comment: So i tried this but initially but I get a build error? 
There is no code highlighting to signify where the error is coming from or anything in the errors tab. I then commented UserNames out and it built ( but without the 'aliased' functionality that I'm looking for )

Comment: @Delrog - You have to set your project properties to be built using c# 7. See this previous answer for where to set that in your project properties https://stackoverflow.com/a/43682193/1260204

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
private string UserName;
public string UserNames
{
  get
  {
    return UserName;
  }  
  set
  {
    UserName=value;
  }
 }
```