# C# 7.0 'out variables' in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-7.0

I would like to compile C# 7.0 solution in Visual Studio 2015, but I have syntax error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNhuL.png)

ErrorMessage : *'DateTime' is a type but is used like a variable.*

This is related to 'out variables' changed in C# 7.0

Unfortunately I can not use VS2017 (community) and [THIS TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMIfb0-U8sE) - not working (master branch is adapted to VS2017 now).

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately in this solution I have over 400 projects and can't add 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers' foreach project.

Comment: You've kinda painted yourself into a corner here.  You want to compile code that uses C# 7.0 features, but you don't want to update to an IDE that supports C# 7.0, and you don't want to use the workaround to add C# 7.0 support to an older IDE.  How many other options do you think there are?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare a `DateTime` variable outside the call and pass the parameter with the `out` keyword like this:

```
DateTime yuorParam;
method( ..., ..., out yourParam);
```

Comment: This is nice workaroud but I would like to know, how to compile c# 7.0 solution with many projects. I can't refactor many projects to older way of declare 'out' variable.

Comment: You will find a working solution on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015)