# Is it possible build a version of Roslyn in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, roslyn

With the current source code, projects which won't load in VS 2015. I also tried some older branches and while the projects load, they seem to be dependent on packages that are no longer available. I don't mind if its older version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use c#7 with Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Not really I just to  build a version Roslyn not the latest so I don't necessarily need  C#7 if I can build a version of Roslyn which is C#6 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the tag on the github repository for [version 1.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/version-1.0.0) that should build under Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I tried that and can load the solution but when I compile the solution I get a lot of errors like: This project requires the Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package to build. Use NuGet Package Restore to download the required files ("powershell .nuget\NuGetRestore.ps1"). The missing file is "D:\home\shane\workgit\roslyn\src\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Toolset.Open\Targets\..\..\..\..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0-rc3-20150616-02\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props". CSharpInteractiveEditorFeatures. When I try to run the ps script I get errors saying the package cant be downloaded.