# Code builds on vs 2017 but not in vs 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, syntax-error, visual-studio-2017, resharper

After building and testing my solution on Visual Studio 2017 (target framework .NET  4.5, vs + resharper) I run it in production environment with Visual Studio 2015 (same target framework).

In this case I receive **syntax error** while trying to build it.

**For example:**

```
public double Frequency
{
    get => _frequency;
    set 
    {
        if (value > 0)
            _frequency = value;
    }
}
```

In VS 2015 I get:

> "*{ or ; expected*"

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific feature you are using for your get definition (expression-bodied members) is specific to C# version 7.0, [as detailed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#more-expression-bodied-members).

So the reason why your code is not compiling is because VS 2015 uses C# 6.0 and VS 2017 uses C# 7.0.

You can change you `get` declaration to the following in order to make it compatible with C# 6.0 and the it will build in VS 2015:

```
get { return _frequency; }
```

---

Although I have never tried it, [after a quick look around the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015), it seems it would be possible for you to use C# 7.0 with Visual Studio 2015 if you would prefer that option. Then you should in theory be able to compile your code without making any changes.

Comment: Ok but why is this happening?

Comment: @MassimoVariolo: I have edited, and I will add some more information soon... I just want to double check a couple of things first

Comment: Even though it's the same framework C# 7 runs on the Roslyn compiler which is independent of the framework (kind of)

Comment: **How to use c# 7 in vs 2015** [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015)

**How to change c# version in vs** [link2](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St)