# enable c# 7.0 function in visual studio express 2013

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, visual-studio-exp-2013

I read about local function definition in c# 7 version and I want to use in 
visual studio express 2013. how can I enable this.Please help me.
thank in advance.

Comment: What is the reason you cannot upgrade to a newer Visual Studio version?

Comment: Also the instructions listed here might work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015

Comment: if I upgrade to visual studio 2017, does it support visual studio express 2013 Code

Comment: You can install both versions alongside each other and find out.

Comment: I don't see any reason why your C# code should stop working after upgrading

Comment: @user9116565 yes, it does support older code bases.

Answer (score -1):

You should upgrade to Visual Studio 2017. I've been porting the same code since Visual Studio 2002 (C# 1.0) and the cases where it failed to compile are very rare!