# out var, the name 'var' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have the following error :

> The name 'var' does not exist in the current context

on this method call :

```
myClient.GetCurrentPadding(out var currentPadding);
```

what can possibly be the problem? I've tried to update the microsoft.net.compilers nugget but in vain

Comment: Are you possibly on an older C# compiler? If so, declare `currentPadding` on the previous line.

Comment: Also, it would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `out var` is correct and is available if you use at least C# 7.0.

This is what the documentation tell about that feature called [out variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables).

So you need to make sure your project is configured to use at least C# 7 feature by following what is explained in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

This is what is explained by the link:

> Right-click on the project node in Solution Explorer and select
>   Properties. Select the Build tab and select the **Advanced** button.
>   In the dropdown, select the version. The following image shows the
>   "latest" setting:
>
> [image]

Comment: I only have C#6 on my VS2015 how can I add c#7 ?

Comment: @MehdiSouregi For VS 2015 follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048660/797882)

Comment: I found out what it the problem, the build succeeds even if my VS2015 keeps underlining the out var error.