# Compiler throws exception for same code in different PC

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Line below in my VS and works fine I checked in and my colleague get these code piece..

```
vm.MuayeneId = (MuayeneId ?? SessionItems.AktifMuayene?.MuayeneId) ?? throw new Exception("Muayene Id bulunamadi");
```

Somehow in his Visual Studio compiler draw the red line under throw keyword and says "; expected". Next line of these code yellow line and says "Unreachable code.."
This is how it looks;
[image]

My colleague has also .NET 4.6.2 installed in his PC.. so what may cause this?

Comment: "My colleague has also .NET 4.6.2 installed in his PC" - but which version of Visual Studio is he using?

Comment: @DaisyShipton VS 2015 community.. I wonder if it cause this as well

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048660/5453249) on how to add C#7 support to VS 2015.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely the problem. I suggest they update to VS2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is called [throw expressions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-throw-expressions) and it was introduced by C# 7.0. I assume your colleques use C# 6.0 or below hence the code does not compile.

Maybe your colleques are able to upgrade Visual Studio to use C# 7.0, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048660/3936440

C# version history can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247623/3936440) posted by John Skeet. According to his list C# 7.0 was released with .NET 4.7 and VS 2017 (March 2017).

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks!