# How fix "C# 7.0 language feature" build errors? (after fresh checkout, previously working)

Tags: c#, c#-7.2, .net-4.7.2

I had a Visual Studio solution that was working fine.  I did a fresh checkout from TFS (with both overwrite checkboxes selected) after deleting the entire source tree.  Now C# 7.0 features are not building.  Projects that do not build have been confirmed to have Target framework = .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Also, in the Advanced Build Settings, C# 7.0 options are not available (even though 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 are all available on my other machine which has not been wiped clean).

How do I fix this?

Environment: Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Update 3, ReSharper 2018.1.3 (6/26/2018), C# 4.7.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try changing var to object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use c#7 with Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c7-with-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: "Environment: Visual Studio Enterprise 2015" - that's the problem. I strongly suspect that your *working* machine has VS2017...

Comment: @jonskeet I had a typo in my original post.  I am using VS2017.  However, I mistakenly opened the project in VS2015.  Good catch!  That's gotta be it.

Comment: the linked answer was NOT the answer to my problem (i.e., I was not seeking to use C# 7 with VS2015 and its NuGet suggested answer was not applicable to my situation)

Comment: there is no warning if a VS2017 sln is accidentally opened in VS2015...the build errors are the first symptom

Answer (score 1):

The VS2017 solution was mistakenly opened in VS2015 (my dev environment requires both regularly).  The solution was obviously to open it in VS2017.

@jonskeet provided the answer in a comment above