# Can I work with latest version of c# with visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have visual studio 2013 installed but I want to use the latest versions of c# . I tried to install visual studio 2017 but it was hard . Is there any way to update my c# version to latest versions ?

Comment: There is also a VS2019... How was installing 2013 "hard"?

Comment: Why would you try to install VS 2017 when it does not support the latest version of C# either?

Comment: The answer is essentially the same for all versions of VS - only VS 2019 supports C# 8, it is possible to use command-line level tools in lower versions but editing would be really painful (see one I selected as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701377/how-can-i-use-c-sharp-8-with-visual-studio-2017). If for whatever reason you can't use VS 2019 consider VS Code or non-Microsoft IDEs like Rider which would give you much more positive expirience with editing code (as you'd not have to fight intellisense/syntax highlighting on every other statement).