# Check sent S2C messages with EventHubConsumerClient using .NET C# 7 and VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-eventhub

I'm starting with IoT Hub and Azure services. I'm following this quickstart tutorial: [Quickstart: Send telemetry from a device to an IoT hub and read it with a back-end application (.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-dotnet)

I [created a Free Tier IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-dotnet#create-an-iot-hub) in my Azure account and [registered a device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-dotnet#register-a-device) using Azure Cloud Shell. Now I'm developing a "starter" library [send D2C messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-dotnet#send-simulated-telemetry) and I can see that it is possible to [read sent messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-dotnet#read-the-telemetry-from-your-hub). I have problems with the last step, it seems that the code is written in C# 8, but I'm developing with VS 2017 and get an error in a `await foreach` loop.

The sample code is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/iot-hub/Quickstarts/read-d2c-messages/ReadDeviceToCloudMessages.cs), and this is the code I want to change to C# 7:

```
private static async Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string connectionString = "{MyConnectionString}";
    await using EventHubConsumerClient consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName, connectionString, EventHubName);
    Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages on all partitions");

    try
    {
        await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumer.ReadEventsAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the error I get in Visual Studio:

**foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IAsyncEnumerable' because 'IAsyncEnumerable' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'**

Is it possible to rewrite this line to use with C# 7?

Some details:

- Visual Studio Professional 2017
- Library target framework: <s>.NET Core 2.1</s> .NET 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use the library without C# 8 by managing the enumerable manually.  The basic form would look something like:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var connection = "<< CONNECTION STRING >>" ;
    var hub = "<< EVENT HUB NAME >>";
    var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connection, hub);
    var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName, connection, hub);

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending...");

        using (var batch = await producer.CreateBatchAsync())
        {
            for (var index = 0; index < 50; ++index)
            {
                batch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(index.ToString())));
            }

            await producer.SendAsync(batch);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Reading...");

        var iterator = consumer.ReadEventsAsync(new ReadEventOptions { MaximumWaitTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500) }).GetAsyncEnumerator();

        try
        {
            var consecutiveEmpties = 0;

            while (await iterator.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var item = iterator.Current;

                if (item.Data != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\tEvent: { Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.Data.Body.ToArray()) }");
                    consecutiveEmpties = 0;
                }
                else if (++consecutiveEmpties > 5)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
           await iterator.DisposeAsync();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done reading.");
    }
    finally
    {
        await producer.CloseAsync();
        await consumer.CloseAsync();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If you prefer, it is also possible to use C# 8 with Visual Studio 2017 by using the latest compilers package, as mentioned in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701377/how-can-i-use-c-sharp-8-with-visual-studio-2017) question.

Apologies; we've been intending a sample to demonstrate but have not yet had the opportunity to implement it.  More context can be found in [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9853) GitHub issue.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. I going to install the latest compiler to use C# new capabilities.