# input string was not in a correct format in DATAGRIDVIEW comparison

Tags: c#, datagridview

when I open the window I select the data to DATAGRIDVIEW :

```
SELECT         result_number as 'Result' , 
               lowerlimit as 'Lower_Limit' , 
               upperlimit  as 'Upper_Limit'
               FROM lab_results
```

I need to change the row color in DATAGRIDVIEW in the following cases :

1- if the result less than lower limit or result greater than upper limit.

2- if the result = positive .

this is example :

```
result        Lower_Limit          Upper_Limit

  7.5              9                    11

  61.4             25                   55

  positive
```

In these 3 result rows I need to change the row color to red I tried the following code :

```
private void dgvResult_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
                      
                if (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString()) < Convert.ToDecimal(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Lower_Limit"].Value.ToString()))

                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

                }

                else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value) > Convert.ToDecimal(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Upper_Limit"].Value))
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
                else if (dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString() == "positive")
            {
               e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString() == "")
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            }

        }
```

but when open the form I got error input string was not in a correct format on first line , how to solve this error please ?

Comment: _dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString() == ""_ so you can have a cell with an empty value? Then you get the exception with trying Convert.To..... use always decimal.TryParse instead and do not call the same operation for every if block, do it just one time at the start

Comment: You should have if clauses for `(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString() == "")` and `(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString() == "positive")` first in if else chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the cells in the result column doesn't contain a number (like the word "positive" or an empty string) then Convert.ToDecimal throws the exception.
But you can use decimal.TryParse to avoid the exception and rearrange your code to check for the non numeric strings before applying the color for the out of range values.

```
private void dgvResult_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    string value = dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Result"].Value.ToString();
    decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal result);
    decimal.TryParse(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Lower_Limit"].Value.ToString(), out decimal lower);
    decimal.TryParse(dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Upper_Limit"].Value.ToString(), out decimal upper);
    if (value == "")
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
    else if (value == "positive" || result < lower || result > upper)
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is error in this line decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal result);  invalid expression term 'decimal'  the out decimal result

Comment: update the solution add first decimal result; decimal lower; decimal upper; then in the line down remove word decimal its working thank you so much :)))

Comment: What version of C# are you using? That syntax has been available for some time now. However, if you can't upgrade just declare the variables before the _TryParse_ and remove the type after the _out_

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015

Comment: Version C# 7.0 See here https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1175809/Csharp-New-Inline-Out-Variables

Comment: And here a QA for upgrading Visual Studio 2015 to use C# 7.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c-sharp-7-with-visual-studio-2015