# Visual Studio 2015 false alarm out keyword reference types as method arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, out

I'm using unity with C# in Visual Studio 2015 and whenever I use something like this:

```
if (!NavMesh.SamplePosition(position, out NavMeshHit hit, 1f, NavMesh.AllAreas)) { return; }
```

or this

```
if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity)) { return; }
```

I get a compile time error warning for `RaycastHit hit` or `NavMeshHit hit` and where ever `hit` is used after that.
if I declare it as local variable the error goes away

```
NavMeshHit hit;
if (!NavMesh.SamplePosition(position, out hit, 1f, NavMesh.AllAreas)) { return; }

RaycastHit hit;
if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) { return; }
```

or by pressing `Ctrl + .` and then `Esc` canceling it, the error goes away and even if it doesn't, it just compiles OK and goes into run-time with no problem.

is there a way to resolve this inside visual studio?

Comment: What is the actual error message, or is it a warning, what is it?

Comment: This is a C# 7 feature so you need at least Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @KlausGütter what is the name of this feature, I don't even know what to search to look for any plugin or workaround, is there a way to turn of that specific warning?

Comment: @Charlieface 'NavMeshHit' is a type but is used like a variable, KlausGütter is right, it seems I need to whether switch to 2017 or just ignore it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Comment: btw this one helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c-sharp-7-with-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a C# 7 feature not available in Visual Studio 2015, you have to whether upgrade to 2017 or just ignore it.

EDIT: ended up using Visual Studio Code at the end, coz for me Visual Studio 2017 was too much of a size, 50GB compared to 2015 with only 9GB