# How can I declare some variables in a conditional statement?

Tags: c#

I'm studying some open source codes and converting them from visual studio version 2017 to 2015.

But I don't know how to convert any code.

I think there is a problem with the declaration of local variables in conditional statement.

This code

```
public static void ManageToolActivation(this IMachineElementViewModel vm, bool value)
        {

            if (vm is ToolHolderViewModel thvm)
            {
                thvm.ActiveTool = value;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in vm.Children)
                {
                    var child = item as MachineElementViewModel;

                    child.ManageToolActivation(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

causes

> The name 'thvm' does not exist in the current context

`ToolHolderViewModel` is a name of other project(class).

It works in visual studio 2017 but not in visual studio 2015. I think there's a problem with declaring variables in conditional statements.

How can I modify this code to work?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: try this....if (vm is ToolHolderViewModel)
            {
                vm.ActiveTool = value;
            }

Comment: The error message I received is as follows. 'The name 'thvm' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Thank you Amit Verma. I tried it on your advice, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Amit is basically right, but you still need a cast. "It doesn't work" is (again) no useful error description.

Comment: I followed Amit's advice and got the following error message. : 'IMachineElementViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ActiveTool' and no extension method 'ActiveTool' accepting a first argument of type 'IMachineElementViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is [Type testing with pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#type-testing-with-pattern-matching), which is a feature of C# 7.0.

The code

```
variable is SomeType castedVariable
```

is a shortcut for

```
if (variable is SomeType)
{
    SomeType castedVariable = variable as SomeType;
}
```

Applied to your case:

```
if (vm is ToolHolderViewModel)
{
     ToolHolderViewModel thvm = vm as ToolHolderViewModel;
     thvm.ActiveTool = value;
}
```

While I doubt backporting a project to an older version of Visual Studio is beneficial, you might also try to [make VS 2015 support C# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461407/how-to-use-c-sharp-7-with-visual-studio-2015).