# v1.0.6 of Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

When I update my dotNet MVC project to use v1.0.6 of Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform I get deployment issues in that the roslyn directory is no longer placed under the bin directory of the deployment.

I have v2.3.1 of Microsoft.Net.Compilers in my project and nothing else is changed in the project other than updating Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform via the Manage NuGet Packages feature of VS2015.

If I revert to v1.0.5 of Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform all works fine.

It appears as if this updated version of Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform is breaking / removing Microsoft.Net.Compilers references from the project.

I tried uninstalling and then re-installing Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform and Microsoft.Net.Compilers from my project but that doesn't solver the issue.

I tried the suggestions in the following StackOverflow article without success.

[Could not find a part of the path ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe)

I also tried to manual copy the roslyn directory to the output directory, but the directory is removed on each build of the project.

I would appreciate if anyone can help shed some light on how to resolve the problem.

Les

Comment: Also experiencing this issue. And can confirm that the fixes in the linked article do not fix it. I will be reverting to 1.0.5.0

Comment: Same here, will also revert for now if this fixes the problem.

Comment: It appears the same issue happens if you open, update and build the project in VS2017.

Comment: The v1.0.7 release solves the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, it looks like a change in the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props` file under packages`\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.6\build\net45`

I added back in a target from the 1.0.5 version by adding back in

```
<Target Name="IncludeRoslynCompilerFilesToItemGroup" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences" >
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="@(RoslyCompilerFiles)" Condition="">
    <Link>%(RoslyCompilerFiles.Link)</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

before

```
<Target Name="CopyRoslynCompilerFilesToOutputDirectory" ... />
```

and publishing is working again.

I think it is being tracked here [link](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/13)

Comment: Rohit, Thanks for the info. I'll try your fix. Les

Comment: Rosly?? or Rosly**n** - it may not work (my answer bellow works - VS 2019) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

1.0.7 was released. Please give it a try. If you see any issue, go to [roslyncodedomprovider github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/roslyncodedomprovider/issues) and file an issue there.

Comment: v1.0.7 does indeed solve the problem. BUT! I had to completely uninstall 1.0.6 and then reinstall 1.0.7. Otherwise, the problem persisted (for the 12 hours it took me to figure this out -- grrrr!).

Answer (score 0):

as i see on my project, removing two lines from the csproj file - solves the problem.
the two lines placed on the end of the csproj XML file, under the tag

<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports"
BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">

inside the tag

```
<PropertyGroup>
```

The two lines are are:

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.3.2\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
```

by removing them - the publishing is back to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in Github's [Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/21) missing **n** (Rosly*CompilerFiles*) instead of Rosly**n***CompilerFiles*, fixed looks like this:

```xml
  <Target Name="CopyRoslynCompilerFilesToOutputDirectory" AfterTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslynCompilerFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" ContinueOnError="true" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="0" />
  </Target>
```

Btw my SampleWebApp.csproj from https://github.com/JonPSmith/SampleMvcWebApp
had this instead (placed Roslyn next2):

```
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
```