# Could not find file '..\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'. after publishing to server

Tags: asp.net, .net, roslyn

My .net application is running well in my local machine. I am using Visual Studio 2015. When I publish the website and upload it to the server space, I am getting the following error.

[image]

I can't understand why the problem has been occurring. My other projects are working well. Is there any problem during the time of publishing?

Any clue?

Thanks

Partha

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe

Answer (score 4):

Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r
You have to run this Code under Package Manual Console PM>
for more details visit [Could not find a part of the path ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `rosalyn` folder is not available in you published `bin` folder.

[image]

If you face difficulties with `rosalyn` see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32780315/1349365)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but in case it helps someone. Just a clean solution and Rebuild solution fixed this for me