# VSTS Build fails/Publish fails to find roslyn\csc.exe in the bin folder

Tags: c#, build, web, azure-devops, roslyn

We have a website project which has the following nuget packages installed

```
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform - 1.0.8

Microsoft.Net.Compilers - 2.4.0
```

The `web.config` has the following

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Builds work fine locally. When the `DotNetCompilerPlatform` is installed the *install.ps1* the script creates the Roslyn folder in the bin and copies csc.exe etc to the folder.

The code is being written by a third party and committed to our VSTS repo. I want to use VSTS to build and deploy the website through our test/stage and prod environments.

The VSTS build pipeline grabs the source, then restores the packages and runs a Visual Studio Build task on the solution. It is a website project so that is no proj for the site. The build fails with the following error

> ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPRUNTIME: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'xxxxxxxxxx\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.

As the build is just doing a restore of the package the R**oslyn binaries are not copied to the bin**.

I also try removing the packages from the project and deleting the compilers from the `web.config` but then get the error.

> Error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'

where I am using some of the newer language features.

I really want to automate the PreCompile and Publish as at the moment there are too many manual steps which are open to error or abuse.

One thought I had was to add a step in the build pipeline after the package restore to run the *install.ps1* from the `DotNetCompilerPlatform` package folder which will hopefully copy the compiler tools to the bin. i.e. mimic what is done when you install the package. But before I went down this road I wanted to see if there was a better solution.

Comment: For us investigate this issue, could you please set system.debug as true and queue a new build, then share the debug log here?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? We are having the same issue with a website project build on azure devops.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is updating your **'.csproj'** to change your build definition(*in the code itself*) like below to `copy the roslyn` directly into `bin` folder rather than the `default output directory`.

```
<Target Name="CopyRoslynFiles" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="!$(Disable_CopyWebApplication) And '$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RoslynFiles Include="$(CscToolPath)\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(RoslynFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)" RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
</Target>
```

[Refer this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780433/7073340)

This way you can't change the VSTS Build definition

Comment: The solution includes a web site project rather than a web application project so does not include a csproj file that can be edited.