# Unknown error executing AWS Serverless deployment: Could not find a part of the path 'PROJECT\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\runtime\rhel.7-x64\'

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-2.1, serverless

I have developed a lambda serverless project with .Net core API and trying to deploy the package using dotnet lambda deploy-serverless

project: AWS lambda serverless .Net core API
target framework: 2.1
error shown in dotnet deploy-servreless

I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe) and many similar topics, about roslyn but doing these tasks didn't solve my issue.

**Update:**
The API project builds with no warnings and even runs with visual studio, calling endpoints don't have any bugs even. The problem occurs deploying with powershell / dotnet lambda command

```html
PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
PM> Uninstall-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

But following the answers didn't solve my problem. I hadn't these packages in my solution and even installing them resulted in conflict warning, with .net core. I don't think my case is about roslyn.

Answer (score 0):

I found a related thread on AWS Github: [dotnet lambda package' failure after framework changing](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/207) But it's closed without answer.

To spot the issues's context and scope,  I tried these tests and relative results:

**Error:** 
Deploying the serverless lambda .net core API breaks. (and changing default targetframework from 1.0 to 2.1)

**Tests:**
Deploying an external serverless lambda .net core API : works
Deploying the simple lambda function  clean template (with changing target framework) : works
Deploying the serverless lambda .Net API clean template (without changing target framework) : works
Deploying the serverless lambda .Net API clean template (with changing target framework) : breaks

**Resolve:**
I created the project using dotnet cli command, it created with version 2.1 (latest in lambda) and packaging/deploying was successful. I guess a fresh install of VS 2017 having netcoreapp2.1 and higher should work fine.

**Environment:**
I am using VS2017 , windows 10.  first installed version of  visual studio had .net core 1.0 and updated to 2.2 using VS update installer.

In fact there might be a bug with Visual studio update installer, some part with net core 1.0 is left behind the user's machine. (Currently every time I create a project it uses 1.0 and not the latest version possible, 2.2 and I should update it manually)