# 'Could not find file ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, roslyn

In Visual Studio 2017, when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to
run my ASP.NET Framework Web API server, I get:

```
Could not find file ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe:
```

[image: Server Error '/' in Application.]

Running
`Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r`
in the package manager console is not a permanent fix in the sense
that the server error appears again when the package files are
missing.
How can I get rid of this error once and for all so that the needed
packages are automatically (and silently) reinstalled as soon as I
reopen, build, and run my Visual Studio solution?

---

Code to reproduce the error:
[https://user.it.uu.se/~hesc0353/RoslynError-reproduce.zip](https://user.it.uu.se/%7Ehesc0353/RoslynError-reproduce.zip)
(Originally from
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetDocs/tree/master/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client/sample/server/ProductsApp)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As you already mention, 
the quick fix is to use the package manager, 
`Tools` > `Nuget Package Manager` > `Package Manager Console`, to run

> ```
> Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r
> ```

as pointed out by 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315#34391473

[image: Packet Manager Console - how to open]

But an alternative solution (which I consider to be more robust) is to remove an attribute of your project's `Web.config` file.
(`Web.config` is in the same directory as your `.csproj` file.)

Open the `Web.config` file in a text editor (or inside Visual Studio).
 - In the tag `configuration | system.codedom | compilers | compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"`, completely remove the `type` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

In short, remove the line that starts with `type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft`.

(Presumably, the same fix works for Visual Basic as well as for Csharp, but I have not tried it.)

Visual Studio will take care of the rest. No more `Server Error in '/' Application`.

In the example code I provided in the zip file above you will now get `HTTP Error 403`
 when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden]

Try replacing `http://localhost:64195` in your web browser with `http://localhost:64195/api/products`.
The web API now displays as it should:

[image: A web API containing products]

As a provocation, I even tried removing the whole `package` directory of my Visual Studio solution.
It was automatically and silently recreated as soon as I (re-)built it.

Comment: This issue has been around for a while, this is the most complete and up to date answer, thanks.