# "The reference component 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' could not be found." for all under References in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

Using VS2017 and .Net 4.7.2, was trying to update the Extent Reports version. Then updated the MongoDB versions etc. Realized that it was the version not supported. So back to the original version of Extent reports (3.x) and MongoDb version 2.11.x. Now suddenly all the references are giving this error message: ***The reference component 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' could not be found***.

Also, at the end getting this error message: ***This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..<folder>\packages\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.signed.1.2.1.1\build\MongoDB.Libmongocrypt.signed.targets.***

Btw, There are two projects involved: P1, an automation framework and P2, the test suite. P1 is the issue. P2 is fine, but can not compile since P1 does not compile and creates a dll.. When I updated the version I have been doing for both projects. The versions are compatible.

How to resolve this issue? Also all the references do not have any paths as shown below in pic2.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use NuGet Package Restore to re-add them?

Comment: Tried it and it says its there: All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious did you also try a clean and rebuild of the project? I am having flashbacks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780315/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-bin-roslyn-csc-exe

Comment: Yes I did, the very first thing.

Comment: Also, I was able to compile the same project before and deployed and works as an automated test suites.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issues:
Edited the .csproj file, to comment out something that was left over during installing and uninstalling of MongoDB. The error is shown at the bottom of the first screen shot.
Since all or none approach taken in getting up the project references, when one failed all are ignored, hence looked like all references failed. Actually, it's only one reference failed.
However, I'm still stuck with some other issues, for which I'll create another question.